# Accessing XML element values with names 'name' and 'value'

Tags: xml, powershell, foreach

In PowerShell, given the following partial XML structure:

```xml
<ExtraAttributes Enabled="1" PerBuildingEnabled="0" PerBuildingMode="0">
  <!--PerBuildingMode 0: Inclusively district and building, Mode 1: Exclusively building-->
  <Attributes>
    <A Enabled="1">
      <name>mail</name>
      <value>$UserPrincipalName</value>
    </A>
    <A Enabled="1">
      <name>ipPhone</name>
      <value>123456</value>
    </A>
  </Attributes>
</ExtraAttributes>
```

If I try to access the value of one of the `value` elements with the following:

```psh
# $ExtraAttributes is extracted as [Xml.XmlElement] from an [Xml.XmlDocument]
foreach ($att in ($ExtraAttributes.Attributes.ChildNodes | where { [int]$_.Enabled -eq $true })) {
    Write-Host "Name: $($att.name), Value: $($att.value)"
}
```

It works just fine...however, if there is only a single `A` element under `Attributes` like so:

```xml
<ExtraAttributes Enabled="1" PerBuildingEnabled="0" PerBuildingMode="0">
  <!--PerBuildingMode 0: Inclusively district and building, Mode 1: Exclusively building-->
  <Attributes>
    <A Enabled="1">
      <name>mail</name>
      <value>$UserPrincipalName</value>
    </A>
  </Attributes>
</ExtraAttributes>
```

Powershell thinks `$att.value` is `$null`.

How can I access those element values when only a single `A` element is present with the same foreach loop? The XML can be restructured, but I'm trying to avoid that.

Comment: The code you posted works just fine with both partial structures when I set `$ExtraAttributes` to the root element of either XML snippet. Hence the problem is most likely with how you select the `<ExtraAttributes>` node from you actual data.

Comment: I would appreciate it if you could un-downvote my question. I did figure it out, although I never discovered the root cause.

The `$ExtraAttributes` element was pulled from the root document in the following format: 

`[xml]$config = Get-Content myfile.xml`
`$ExtraAttributes = $config.Configuration.District.ExtraAttributes`

If there is a better way to do so, I would like to know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using `childNodes`, I used the element name `A` as such:

```
foreach ($att in ($ExtraAttributes.Attributes.A | where { [int]$_.Enabled -eq $true })) {
Write-Host "Name: $($att.name), Value: $($att.value)"
}
```

And it works as expected whether there is only one or multiple `A` elements. I never figured out why `childNodes` doesn't allow it to work.